# Making changes in Firefox print does not work , but works well in other browsers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox

I am trying to modify some content for print alone, and so have a hook

```
import { useState } from 'react'

const usePrint = () => {
    const [isPrinting, setIsPrinting] = useState(false)
    const handleBeforePrint = () => {
        setIsPrinting(true)
    }
    const handleAfterPrint = () => {
        setIsPrinting(false)
    }

    typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.addEventListener('beforeprint', handleBeforePrint)
    typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.addEventListener('afterprint', handleAfterPrint)

    return isPrinting
}

export default usePrint
```

In the code I check the usePrint Value and display content accordingly

```
const testVar = usePrint() ? 'It is Printing' : 'It is not printing'
```

While displaying testVar, it works well in chrome, with 'It is printing' getting displayed in print preview. But this does not work in Firefox. How can we get this to work in firefox

Tried a Codesandbox and used just window.alert. The alert comes up before print preview in CHROME but not in firefox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/add-window-event-listener-forked-p5gyiv?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Have you tried with parenthesis : usePrint()

Comment: Yes, still does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the `alert` box blocks other events, in Firefox and in Chrome, but Chrome blocks the print dialog until the `alert` is dismissed. Firefox displays the print dialog right away.

The `alert` is not visible before closing the print dialog in Firefox, I suppose that is because it is displayed, but behind the print dialog. So you need to close the print dialog to dismiss the `alert`, and so any further event handlers (including additional `beforePrint` event handlers) execute at an unexpected time, i.e. when the last `alert` is closed.

When I use only a `console.log` (no `alert`), then all the events fire at the expected time.

The `setState` works as expected for me (if no `alert` is involved).

I was referring to your codesandbox example:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    //...

    window.addEventListener("beforeprint", (event) => {
      window.alert("Before print1");
    });

    window.onbeforeprint = (event) => {
      window.alert("Before print2");
    };

    // ...
  }, []);
```

If you replace the `window.alert` by `console.log` it should work.

#### Other remarks

In your example code block in your question, new event handlers are added on every execution of `usePrint()`. You should use a `useEffect` with a cleanup function, as you (incompletely) did in you codesandbox example.

```
const usePrint = () => {

    // ...

    // This adds a new event handler every time:
    typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.addEventListener('beforeprint', handleBeforePrint)  

}
```